# Getting the Proper Format

Tags: formatting, margins

I have to submit a thesis in a proper format.  What I need to do is have the left margins be 1.5 inches, every other margin 1 inch.  I also need the page number to be in the upper right corner of every page, without exceeding the margins.  Finally, I need to have all the pages before the proper part of my thesis to be written in Roman numerals.  My preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs,mathtools}

%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[total={6in,9in},
top=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\usepackage{multind}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cite}



\pagestyle{plain}
```

What happens is that every other page has the correct margins, but every other page makes the 1.5 inch margin on the right instead of left.  I have tried to look up how to change the page number, which led me to fancyhdr, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Add the `oneside` option next to `12pt`; for `geometry` you don't need `total=`, setting the margins is sufficient.

Comment: Does `amsart` allow a `oneside` option?

Comment: @jon: It does, this option is defined in the `amsart` document class. `:)`

Comment: @egreg I tried both \documentclass[12pt][onside]{amsart} and \documentclass[12pt]{onside}{amsart}, but neither worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `oneside` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}

\usepackage[top=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

This won't alternate between "recto" and "verso" pages, so the wider margin will always be on the left and the page number always in the same position.

For numbering pages with different formats, do in this way:

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

<preliminary material>

\pagenumbering{arabic}

<main material>

\end{document}
```

<sub>Rather than a "proper format" I'd speak about an "imposed format". There's nothing particularly beautiful in such a format. It's just "put as much words on a page as possible".</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't think to put it inside.  That worked like a charm to fix that problem.  Any advice on the other issues?

Comment: Any advice on how to move the page number to the upper right hand corner?  With that you'll have answered everything.

Comment: Got the page number thing fixed.  Thanks for your help.